# How do I add my own table to ASP Membership Provider?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-membership, primary-key

No sure how to relate my own tables into the ASP Membership provider tables. For example the User table, the userID datatype is UniqueIdentifier however if it was an INT it would have been easy to add my own tables.

Can I somehow change the datatype? What would be the best way to go around this?
Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what do you want to accomplish? You may create your own table and create (or add) a 'relationship' between those tables.

Comment: Yes, I wish to do that but the ASP Membership provider creates a user table and the datatype for the userID is 'UniqueIdentifier' however the tables I want to create is INT. The datatypes clash therefore I can't relate them